# dynamicaly create arrayList in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I need to create `50 arraylists` but rather than having to initialise them all individually. Is there a way in JAVA that I can do this dynamically??

i.e.

pseudo code:

```
for int i=1; i<51; i++
List<String> Counti = new ArrayList<String>();
```

So that in the loop it goes through and create 50 arraylists all called `Count1, Count2, Count3` etc up until `Count50`.

I've tried creating a string and then naming the list by the string but it doesnt seem to recognise that teh name is a variable.

e.g.

```
for int i=1; i<51; i++
String Name="Count "+i
List<String> Name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Instead it just creates a list called `"Name"`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I declare and define variables with generated names and values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277156/can-i-declare-and-define-variables-with-generated-names-and-values)

Comment: Why you just trying to change naming i think you are adapting from javascript :) , create lists and add another list in java way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assigning variables with dynamic names in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with reflection, but this is a pretty bad idea. What you probably want to do is create an arraylist of arraylists.

```
 ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
      listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: Consider using List<List<String>> instead of the implementation class as a type, as it is easier to adapt in the future and makes sure that you only rely on the List Interface.

Comment: Prove me wrong, but as far as I know you can't do List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(); @LionC

Comment: @Pier-AlexandreBouchard List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>(); works fine for me. You can then add as many (even different implementations) List<String> as you like to it. The error in your line is the second ArrayList, which has to be a simple List, so that the type matches.

Answer (score 1):

You should store them in a `List` and not create 50 variables

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    lists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Comment: This answer AND the previous answer from Pier both have the same mistake (missing closing bracket)

Comment: This snippet won't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `List` of `ArrayList`.

```
List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    lists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Comment: I guess Stefan noticed the same

Comment: Okay, maybe I should elaborate further, im using this as part of a larger piece of code where I am:

Comment: OK? And this should work for the part of larger piece of code where you are.

Comment: im using this as part of a larger piece of code:

creating an List of length 50 within a for loop (each result different). After each iteration store the results creating 50 rows of arraylists. Be able to do some processing at the end E.g. pick out element 0 of each arraylist.
I tried creating a List of arraylists but it only outputs a list of 50 arraylists with the same results. I think after each iteration the array lists are updated.
I want the first item in the list of array lists to be as at after the first iteration of the for loop.

I cant think of another way of doing this?

Comment: Im a coding beginner so my code is really cluncky and trying to keep up with the logic behind stuff. Most of the code outputs what I want but in a really inefficient way! except I cant get the 50 different arraylists and be able to process them all.

Comment: Consider using List<List<String>> instead of the implementation class as a type, as it is easier to adapt in the future and makes sure that you only rely on the List Interface. Also List is spelled with a capital L :-)

Answer (score 0):

one another possible solution is to use a `HashMap` like this to name the `ArrayLists`:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> mAllArrayListsByName = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < 50 ; i++){
  mAllArrayListsByName.put("List"+String.valueOf(i), new ArrayList<String>());
}
ArrayList<String> lMyArrayList = mAllArrayListsByName.get("List0"); // get List 0
```